# InvalidCastException in Linq Query with String vs NvarChar(20). Lengths are ok

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am receiving an InvalidCastException error in the following code where the linq query runs...

```
System.InvalidCastException was caught
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Specified cast is not valid.
  Source=System.Data.Linq
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
       at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
       at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
       at PINProcess.Program.readCompoundFile(String logFile, String ConnectionString, FileInfo fInfo, ArrayList errors, Int32& putOnHold, Int32 TOId, String FeedFilename, String fileExtension, ArrayList NotFoundPINs) in c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\PINProcess\Program.cs:line 110
  InnerException:
```

Code...

```
string PIN = line.Substring(8, 17); // PIN Number
string InDateTime = line.Substring(25, 14); //Date for In/Out from system  
int vehicleMasterID = 0;
try
{
    DataContext dc = new DataContext(ConnectionString);

    //get MasterId from PIN number
    var q = dc.Masters.SingleOrDefault(v => v.Dead == false && v.PINNo.ToUpper().Trim() == PIN.ToUpper().Trim());
    MasterID = q.Id;

    etc.....
```

So, as far as I can see the error is occurring in the linq query. I do not understand why it is having a problem as the values are there to be found and this works for the for first 3 records then hits the InvalidCastException. `PIN` is a String and `PINNo` in the db is nvarchar(20) so I'm not sure where the error is coming from. The length of `PIN` never exceeds 20 and is always very similar to the ones that do work and do not draw the error.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Why didn't you include the error message?  Like, the most important piece of information we would need in order to help you?

Comment: ...and while you are busy copy'n'pasting the error message here, also take a little time looking at the stacktrace of the exception you got. The code lines in your question obviously do not do any casting explicitly, so the problem originates somewhere 'deeper'...

Comment: Any InnerException information in the exception you got?

Comment: InnerException = null
```A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll```

Comment: you did not mention that the field PINNo does not accept null. Do you have any null values for this column in your database?

Comment: No, there are no null values as this field does not accept nulls.

Comment: What database are you using? Is an exception thrown if you run `var q = dc.Masters.SingleOrDefault(v => v.Dead == false && v.PINNo.ToUpper().Trim() == PIN.ToUpper().Trim());`? What about `var q = dc.Masters.SingleOrDefault(v => v.Dead == false`? What about `var q = dc.Masters.SingleOrDefault(v => v.Dead == false && v.PINNo == PIN);`? What about `var q = dc.Masters.SingleOrDefault(v => v.Dead == false && v.PINNo == PIN.ToUpper().Trim());`

Comment: MS SQL - thanks but those linq queries do not work.

Comment: If **none** of them work, there is likely a problem with your mapping. In other words, your database columns and your classes have different data types.

Comment: Sorry, the one that is the same as in the example I gave works. What is weird here is that the error occurs after several successful linq queries.

Comment: What is the value of `PIN` when it occurs?